# How to construct a SQL sub-query?

Tags: sql, oracle

```
select
e.EMPNO,
e.ENAME
from  
emp e
where 
e.DEPTNO in  (select case
                      when 'D'='D'  then q'[10,20]'
                       END DPT 
                  from dual )
```

**Edit:**

the real query is something like

```
SELECT e.name, e.entid
  FROM ent e
 WHERE     e.etype = 'DPT'
       AND e.entid IN (
                        SELECT CASE
                                WHEN :P96_GP_TYPE = 'R' THEN q'['QUA','SAMP']'
                                WHEN :P96_GP_TYPE = 'REWR' THEN q'['WASH','FNISH']' END
                        FROM DUAL
                      )
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: i need result 

like
select
e.EMPNO,
e.ENAME
from  
scott.emp e
where 
e.DEPTNO in (10,20)

Comment: And why can't you use the query you have? Do you need to get a variable set of data from a table, instead of  hardcoding 10,20?

Comment: Please run my query

Comment: if i use only one value it's working

select
e.EMPNO,
e.ENAME
from  
scott.emp e
where 
e.DEPTNO in  (select case
                      when 'D'='D'  then q'[10]'
                       END DPT 
                  from dual )

if i use only multiple value it's show error


select
e.EMPNO,
e.ENAME
from  
scott.emp e
where 
e.DEPTNO in  (select case
                      when 'D'='D'  then q'[10,20]'
                       END DPT 
                  from dual )

Comment: Please have a look at [ask] and [mcve] to improve your question. As is, it's completely unclear why you want to overcomplicate a query to get the same result of a simple query that you already have

Comment: Can you just do `SELECT empno, ename FROM emp WHERE deptno in (10,20);`? Why the subquery? Documentation on the `IN` condition can be found [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/conditions013.htm)

Comment: if i use only one value it's working

select
e.EMPNO,
e.ENAME
from  
scott.emp e
where 
e.DEPTNO in  (select case
                      when 'D'='D'  then q'[10]'
                       END DPT 
                  from dual )

if i use only multiple value it's show error


select
e.EMPNO,
e.ENAME
from  
scott.emp e
where 
e.DEPTNO in  (select case
                      when 'D'='D'  then q'[10,20]'
                       END DPT 
                  from dual )

Comment: The question here is: "why can't you use the plain query and you want to use a subquery?" What is the result you want to get with a subquery?

Comment: if you want to learn subqueries usage then u can learn from tutorials on net

Comment: Aleksej it's example my real query complicated

select 
e.name,
e.entid
from  ent e  
where e.etype='DPT' 
and   e.entid in (select case
                           when :P96_GP_TYPE='R'     then q'['QUA','SAMP']'
                           when :P96_GP_TYPE='REWR'  then q'['WASH','FNISH']'
                          END 
                  from dual)

Comment: My issue has been resolved i used union clause select 
e.name,
e.entid
from  ent e  
where   e.entid in (select case
                           when :P96_GP_TYPE='R'     then 'SAMP'
                           when :P96_GP_TYPE='REWR'  then 'WASH'
                          END 
                  from dual)
union all
select 
e.name,
e.entid
from  ent e  
where    e.entid in (select case
                           when :P96_GP_TYPE='R'     then 'QUA'
                           when :P96_GP_TYPE='REWR'  then 'FINISH'
                          END 
                  from dual)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a subquery for this, but you can better use a bit of boolean logic:

```
SELECT e.name, e.entid
  FROM ent e
 WHERE     e.etype = 'DPT'
       AND (
                (:P96_GP_TYPE = 'R' AND e.entid IN ('QUA','SAMP') )
                 OR
                (:P96_GP_TYPE = 'REWR'  AND e.entid IN ('WASH','FNISH') )
           )
```

To clarify where your approach fails, consider that these three queries are fully equivalent:

```
select *
from someTable
where someColumn in (  q'['X','Y']' )           

select *
from someTable
where someColumn in ( 
                     select q'['X','Y']'
                     from dual 
                    )

select *
from someTable
where someColumn in ( 
                     select '''X'',''Y'''
                     from dual 
                    )
```

If you want to use a subquery to get a list of values, not a literal that seems like a list of values, you need something like:

```
select *
from someTable
where someColumn in (
                        select 'X'
                        from dual
                        UNION ALL
                        select 'Y'
                        from dual 
                    )
```